# How to calculate wifi download speed during download file in android

Tags: android

```
  private String downloadFile(String MY_URL) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            fileName = MY_URL.substring(MY_URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, MY_URL.length());
            File outputFile = new File(directory, fileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    total += count;
                    int status = (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile);
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    handler.post(() -> {
                        progress_circular_id.setProgress(status);
                        textview_progress_status_id.setText(String.valueOf(status) + "%");
                        if (status == 100) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            appSharedPreferences.setStatusFileDownloading(false);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            return "Downloaded at: " + directory.getPath() + fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Abhan", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            runOnUiThread(() -> customLoader.hide());
        }
        customLoader.hide();
        return "Downloading Error";
    }
```

This is my code  for download file from Wifi file downloading successfully in SD Card . I want to get Download speed of file while downloading in process I have total file size of value in that basis i want to calculate total time left to complete the download file in SD card .

Comment: How the calculation should be done we would leave to you. But if you want to measure the download speed then just tell.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps ejectly i want  get download speed and how much time it will take with that speed  in second

Comment: Well write your post in that way. And tell exactly what you want to measure and where exactly you have a difficulty.

Comment: ???? Well you did not add any relevant info or problem description or question. Come to the point please.

Comment: can you please check now i have edit my question let me know if still information is not clear so that i will try to improve more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252122/discussion-between-marsh-and-blackapps).

Comment: No chat. And nothing is clear. You did not give the info i asked for. I dont keep asking.